# How to call a value of choice list in template from module in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Please help to call all posts' title that have a particular category in my template. This is my code:

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


class Post(models.Model):
    choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('name', 'name')
    choice_list = []
    first=Priority.objects.all().values_list('prior_name','prior_name')
    prior_list=[]
    for i in first:
        prior_list.append(i)
    for i in choices:
        choice_list.append(i)

    title  = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    priority=models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=prior_list, null=True)
    date_posted= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author =models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    category=models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=choice_list)

    snippet=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

and here is the views.py. which is incorrect since it just sorts all posts

```
def topics(request):
  context = {
       'posts': Post.objects.all()
   }
  return render(request,'blog/list_of_topics.html',context)
```

And this is code from template

```
{% for post in posts %}

        <ul  style=" text-align:center">
           <li><a  href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{post.title}}</a></li>

        </ul>

{% endfor %}
```

I guess i have to write. some kind of condition but i am not sure how to do it, I want to sort all my posts title based on category, which is category variable in Post model

Thank you in advance, will appreciate any tips

Answer (score 0):

Normally you could filter your queryset in the view, so instead of `Post.objects.all()` you could have something like `Post.objects.filter(category='some category name')`. Then pass the filtered queryset in the context to the template.

But otherwise the code you show contains several things which don't fully make sense:

#### Category & Post

It seems you are trying to create a Category that can be used to categorize posts. Usually this relation would be specified with a ForeignKey field on the Post object and not by duplicating the category name on the Post again, such as:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Post(models.Model):
   ...
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True)
   ...
```

#### Code in Post class namespace

You are writing code directly in the Post class namespace. While this will probably not throw an error, it is highly unlikely that it would do what you expect it. But I'm not sure what you expect to happen with that exactly.

Let me know if this helps.